# Is there a specific set of optional args requirements for puppeteer headless performance

Tags: c#, puppeteer, chromium, playwright, puppeteer-sharp

I am using puppeteersharp (C# port of puppeteer) chromium headless mode to generate pdf from html.

By default it passes some default args to chromium.

Default args are available at below link in constant name `chromeArguments`

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/node/Launcher.ts

After going through the discussion at [google group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/headless-dev/c/f_tQUs__Yqw)

I have added additional args along with default args.

```
--disable-notifications,
--disable-translate,
--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update,
--remote-debugging-port=9222,
--disable-setuid-sandbox,
--disable-gpu,
--user-agent=true,
--hide-scrollbars,
--no-sandbox,
--no-zygote,
--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required,
--disable-logging,--disable-permissions-api,
--disable-databases,
--ignore-certificate-errors,
--ignore-ssl-errors,
--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list,
--mute-audio,
--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw,
--no-default-browser-check
```

If I am using puppeteer for converting html to pdf only , which all additional options are required in respect of getting good performance (min memory and cpu usage)?

Or If above is not possible is there any way I can limit memory usage from c# for background process for chromium?